# What does this symbol mean in this equation?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I am reading up on n-choose-k problems (Binomial Coefficients).

Wikipedia gives a multiplicative solution that is more efficient:

[image: What symbol?]

I've taken a few calculus courses, and it reminds me of how you would use the summation symbol ∑, but it also kind of looks like pi (π).  What is this symbol and how can I use it to understand this formula?

Comment: It is like summation but for multiplication.

Comment: Is there also a name for the symbol?  I've never encountered it in all my studies (granted I'm a CS major, but we have a few math courses under our belt).

Comment: It is product, since $\pi$ is the greek letter for $p$.

Comment: It is called pi.

Comment: It is capital $\pi$ (standing for Product).

Comment: Ah I see.  I'm surprised I've never encountered a formula using this before.  Now it makes much more sense!

Comment: You may find this useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols. The symbol you are looking for is listed near the bottom of that page.

Comment: It's the capital Greek letter, pi, for "product," the same way we use the capital Greek letter, sigma ($\Sigma$) for "sums."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\prod$ means product just as $\sum$ means sum.
So, $\prod_{i=1}^5 i = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5$

Most often, it is defined as:
$$ \prod_{i=0}^0 a_i = a_0 $$
$$ \prod_{i=0}^n a_i = (\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i)\cdot a_n$$

Answer (score 1):

$\prod_{k=1}^{n} k = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots n$, i.e. a product sighn

Answer (score 1):

*Pi* as in *product*:

$\prod_{k=1}^n a_k=a_1\cdot a_2\cdots a_{n-1}\cdot a_n$.

Comment: $k=1$, you meant? You have $k-1$

Comment: Corrected it. Thanks.